# focus on a div field

Tags: jquery, focus, fancybox

I am trying to focus to a div (fancybox modal) when user click on a dropdown box. I have tried setting tabindex on the div. It focus alright however display a scrollbar at the bottom of the modal window.

Having read that links, input elements, textareas, etc can be set to focus on, I have tried focus a hidden input in the modal div with no avail.

more details: it is a user registration page with all countries and cities loaded hidden in the page. a fancybox modal pops up with content of the hidden countries and cities displayed when user click on the city dropdown box. from there, user can click through country, state then city. in the end, the chosen city gets filled in the previous dropdown and fancybox closed.

The problem is that user clicks on dropdown and the focus stays there after the fancybox popsup.

Code:

```
$("select[name=current_home]").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'overlayShow'   : false,
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'width'         : 300,
        'content'       : '<div id="countries">' + $('#countries-box').html() + '</div>',
        'onComplete'    : function() { $('#countries').focus(); },

    });
   //       $('#countries input[name=focusme]').focus();
});
```

the `countries-box` hold the hidden countries and cities. I wasn't using the `onComplete` provided by fancybox as you can see the above commented line. I tried both and no difference.

any solution?

Comment: Can you clarify where this div and dropdown box is, any relevant code would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you're trying to focus `<div id="countries>`, and divs can't be focused, neither they transfer focus to inside focusable elements.

You need to focus an `input`, `select`, `textarea` or `button` inside your div on it's `onComplete` event firing, and a good way would be to focus the first one, like this:

```
$.fancybox({
    ...
    'onComplete' : function(){ $('#countries :input:visible:enabled:first').focus()}
    ...
});
```

`:input` checks for `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button` elements, as explained in [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: no. you misunderstood in your second paragraph. the input filed was for a workaround and is actually a hidden filed I was trying to focus. it is located in the fancybox. but you mentioned that focus doesn't work on hidden field.

Comment: that's right, then you should focus the NON hidden first field, i'm updating the jquery call!

Comment: For your answer: there isn't any input filed in the fancybox window for me to focus on. that's why I was trying to make a hidden one and thought that would do the trick. SO without form element, how do I do the focus?

Comment: As you say, you have dropdown boxes, you can focus those the same way... i'm updating the answer.